# Cannot run JavaFX JAR built using Maven from IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have been trying to set up a JavaFX project to prepare for a school project and I wanted to use Maven to make it easier to share it as it removes the need for configuration as long as the `pom.xml` file is correctly written.

I can compile the project, run it with `javafx:run` but when I use the maven jar plugin to generate a JAR I get the following error trying to run it :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.openjfx.App
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I don't understand why it's not finding the JavaFX classes as I do have the JavaFX Maven plugin as well as the `javafx-controls` and `javafx-fxml` dependencies added in the `pom.xml`

Here's the full file for reference

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.openjfx.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing for the JAR to include the JavaFX classes ? I thought adding the maven plugin was enough.

Thank you

Comment: See the javafx-maven-plugin documentation, run javafx:jlink

Comment: See [_javafx:jlink options_](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options) for details.

Comment: I must admit I don't really understand how it works. I managed to make it run by add adding a `module-info.java` file when before it didn't run at all but I'm not getting a jar and instead I have an executable in target/app/bin

Comment: Yes. That is the point, you most likely want an executable. That is something you can execute, rather than a jar, which you cannot. You can apply the zip option for the javafx-maven-plugin to get something easily distributable.  Then somebody can just download, unzip it and run it.